# How to split line with trace by specific length in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, editing

I'm modifying the existing water pipeline network. Sometimes I have information that the pipe from the beginning to the 125meter has a diameter 63mm after that point it has a 100meter -diameter 50mm and the rest of it 32mm.
I need to split that 1 pipe into 3 pipes:

- 125meter,
- 100meter,
- and the rest of what was left (to give different diameter attributes(63,50,32)).

And I also need it to be modified in the same shapefile.
Advanced digitizing and v.split don't work in this situation.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how the `split lines by length` tool works?

Comment: Previously I was working in ArcGIS pro and it was very easy and fast to solve this kind of problem(splite tool- trace by length limit). It just modifies the lines as required.
In Qgis I can't find the right tools to do this.

Comment: Well, have you tried the `split lines by length` tool?`

Comment: If you mean GRASS- v.splite  then yes (I can't find other split lines by length tool). it creates a new layer but does not modify existing.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround:

Create a point layer with points as the split distances using "Geometry by expression":

```
collect_geometries(array_foreach( array(100,225), end_point(line_substring( $geometry, 0, @element))))
```

Snap the split tool line to the points